# Redshift Correlated Subquery within copy command

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to query from a table within a copy command however, I have continually gotten errors. Here is the example SQL statement.

```
copy schema.table
from 's3://bucket/folder`
iam_role (select value from roles.iam where key = 'IAMRole');
```

The inner select statement on its own returns a value however, when I run the above, I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [500310] [42601]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "("
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `COPY` command, as you must suspect, does not support embedded SQL.

If you want to do something like this, you can, but you'll need a procedure.

Comment: can you explain how to do this within a procedure

Comment: There's plenty of docs on line about procedures in Redshift.  You'll need to learn how to do it; it's too complex for someone to guide you step by step here.  You do however now know one way in which to solve te problem, and so what to go and learn about.